# Comparing two lists of instances of the same class, by a specific instance attribute only

Tags: python

I have two lists of instances of the class below. I want to compare whether the two lists contain the same data (order is unimportante) in the doc_data attribute.

```
class Class_Test:
    type: str
    def __init__(self, doc_data: Dict, meta_data: Dict):
        self.doc_data = doc_data
        self.meta_data = meta_data
```

I thought of sorting a list of instances of Class_Test, by the values in the keys of doc_data, only.
The problem is that not all instances have the same keys...
All instances keys belong to a superset -> {key_1, ..., key_n}
But some instances have only key_1, key_7, while other may only have key_2, key_4.
I suspect it may not be possible to sort consistently in this situation. Nevertheless, there may exist someone with a better idea, like using set().

Comment: *not all instances have the same keys* - do you consider that initially as a valid case?

Comment: _some instances have only key_1, key_7, while other may only have key_2, key_4_ Okay, so how should this situation be handled?  What should the code actually do?  You haven't said what the actual sorting rules are...

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two dictionaries in python with == (I assume Dict is a python dictionary, it is good to always provide reproducible code with examples), so you don't need to "look inside" the dictionaries if you only care if they are equal.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)
: *Dictionaries compare equal if and only if they have the same (key, value) pairs (regardless of ordering).*

You did not specify what happens if you have multiple Class_Test that have the same contents of doc_data. I will assume you want to check if both lists have the same number of Class_Test equal objects.

```
class Class_Test:
    type: str
    def __init__(self, doc_data: dict, meta_data: dict={}):
        self.doc_data = doc_data
        self.meta_data = meta_data

    # To be able to use in print
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.doc_data)

list1 = [Class_Test({'k1':1,'k2':2}),
         Class_Test({'k3':1,'k4':4}),
         Class_Test({'k3':1,'k4':4}),
         Class_Test({'k5':1,'k6':2})]

list2 = [Class_Test({'k1':1,'k2':2}),
         Class_Test({'k4':1,'k3':4}),
         Class_Test({'k4':4,'k3':1}),
         Class_Test({'k4':4,'k3':1}),
         Class_Test({'k99':1,'k4':4}),
         Class_Test({'k88':1,'k6':2})]

common = []
list2_copy = list2.copy()
for x in list1:
    # Find the elements that are the same as x
    indices = [i for i in range(0,len(list2_copy)) if list2_copy[i].doc_data == x.doc_data]
    if len(indices)>0:
        # We found some elements, we remove them and add them to the result
        del list2_copy[indices[0]]
        common += [x]

print(f"Common values are: {common}")
```

Results in:

```
Common values are: [{'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}, {'k3': 1, 'k4': 4}, {'k3': 1, 'k4': 4}]
```

Checking then if lengths of list1, list2 and common are the same will tell you if the lists contain exactly the same elements.

Note: **repr** was added to that I can print and meta_data default initialization was added so that I create object easier